# React Native - Can't get section headers to stick in ListView

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

I'm going around in circles trying to figure out why I can't get section headers to stick at the top of my React Native `<ListView>`, but nothing seems to be helping.

I am pretty sure that I am implementing the required method `renderSectionHeader` correctly and my `dataBlob` object is correctly structured - I am able to get the `<ListView>` to render fine, it's just the section headers aren't sticking...

Can anyone see something obvious that I've overlooked?

Root Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View
} from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Content
} from 'native-base';
import TabFooter from '../../Components/Footer';
import ListViewWithSections from '../../Components/ListViewWithSections';

class Accommodation extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    // function that structures data into something suitable for ListView
    const formatDataForListView = accommodation => {
      const dataBlob = {};
      const sectionIDs = [];
      const rowIDs = [];
      let sectionID = -1;

      accommodation.forEach((accom) => {
        sectionID++;
        sectionIDs.push(accom.id);
        dataBlob[accom.id] = accom.name;
        rowIDs[sectionID] = []; // initialise empty array associated with Section ID
        accom.guests.forEach((guest) => {
          rowIDs[sectionID].push(guest.id);
          dataBlob[accom.id + ':' + guest.id] = guest;
        });
      });

      console.log('dataBlob: ', dataBlob);
      console.log('sectionIDs: ', sectionIDs);
      console.log('rowIDs: ', rowIDs);

      return { dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs };
    };

    const { accommodation } = this.props;
    const { dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs } = formatDataForListView(accommodation);
    this.setState({ dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <ListViewWithSections
            dataBlob={this.state.dataBlob}
            sectionIDs={this.state.sectionIDs}
            rowIDs={this.state.rowIDs}
          />
        </Content>
        <View>
          <TabFooter />
        </View>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { accommodation: state.accommodation };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Accommodation);
```

ListViewWithSections.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ListView,
  Row,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class ListViewWithSections extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const getSectionData = (dataBlob, sectionID) => dataBlob[sectionID];
    const getRowData = (dataBlob, sectionID, rowID) => dataBlob[sectionID + ':' + rowID];

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
      sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2,
      getSectionData,
      getRowData
    });

    const { dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs } = this.props;
    console.log('RowIDs new: ', rowIDs);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(dataBlob, sectionIDs, rowIDs)
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log('ListView this: ', this);
    const renderRow = (data) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{data.name}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    };

    const renderSectionHeader = (sectionData, sectionID) => {
      console.log('sectionData: ', sectionData);
      console.log('sectionID: ', sectionID);
      return (
        <View>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: '700' }}>{sectionData}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    };

    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={renderRow}
        renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ListViewWithSections;
```

Comment: I'm developing for iOS at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered from [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1974#issuecomment-144799173) to an issue posted where somebody wanted to not have sticky headers that if the `<ListView>` is nested inside a `<ScrollView>` then the sticky headers don't stick.

I have been using NativeBase as a basis for building my app's UI and the `<Content>` component, I believe, inherits from `<ScrollView>`.

Anyway, when I take it out of the `<Content>` and `<Container>` components the sticky headers work fine.